# Access Azure KV from consumption plan Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Key Vault deployed in a VNET with public access disabled. I need to get secrets from that KV from a consumption Azure function, which is serverless.
The problem is that, as that type of function cannot be deployed in a VNET, I'm facing some networking problems when getting the secret:
[image]

The function has system assigned managed identity on and has Key Vault Administrator role on that KV. I cannot use access policies.

My question is if I can solve the problem without upgrading to Functions premium and how. Getting KV secrets from a function is so common that I'm sure there is a solution for this.

Comment: Could you confirm the details are correct: - 1) Azure Function is in Consumption Plan and cannot be deployed in the VNet 2) Key Vault is in the VNet where Public Access is denied 3) You want to retrieve the KV Secret from the Azure Function without adding the Function to the VNet?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: @Rorepio can you share your function code

Comment: Unfortunately, currently it is not possible to get secrets from KV inside VNET using consumption plan function. check [doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#access-network-restricted-vaults), [doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli)

Answer (score 1):

As Vivek says in the comments, it's not possible to get secrets from KV using consumption plan.

I ended up deploying it in App service service plan, configured the outbound rules within a subnet under the same VNET as the key vault, turned on function app's identity and gave the function 'Key vault secrets officer' role in the key vault, and it works fine.